# A coin is tossed several times and the outcomes are being recorded in a string of H and T. How long - on average - will you have to wait for an "TTH?"

Tags: probability, algorithms, expected-value, python, simulation

> Problem. A coin is tossed several times and the outcomes are being recorded in a string of H (heads) and T (tails). For example, that is recorded as "HHTTTHTH," so, how long - on average - will you have to wait for an "TTH ?"

I need to a plan of solving by simulation via python. Here is the algorithm:

First make a while loop for flipping coins. Then make booleans for each of the states $s_{0}, s_{1}, s_{2}, s_{3}:$
$s_{i}$ means that we have made $i$ progress on getting "TTH." For example, $s_{2}$ means that our last 2 flips were "TT."
If $E_{i}$ is the expected number of flips until we get to $s_{3}$ given that we are on $s_{i},$ then we are looking for the value of $E_{0}.$
We have the following system using states
$$E_{0}= 1+ \frac{1}{2}E_{1}+ \frac{1}{2}E_{0}$$
$$E_{1}= 1+ \frac{1}{2}E_{0}+\frac{1}{2}E_{2}$$
$$E_{2}= 1+ \frac{1}{2}E_{2}+ 0$$
This means
$$E_{2}= 2$$
$$E_{0}- E_{1}= 2$$
$$2E_{1}- E_0= 4$$
$$E_{1}= 6$$
$$\boxed{E_{0}= 8}$$
Now just simulate the progress the flip makes toward the final state by changing the values of each of the booleans until it gets to the final state.
Also you would have to repeat this process a sufficient number of trials and take the average number of flips of all trials.
**Edit**. What is the probability of it takes 8 trials to wait for an "TTH ?" Hope can you help... thanks a real lot !

Comment: The answer is $8$ if you want to check your simulation is working

Comment: The logic you propose is good, and you can even use it to solve the problem exactly.  Let $E_i$ be the expected number of tosses it will take, given that you are in state $s_i$ and write out the linear equations connecting the $E_i$.

Comment: The plan is already the algorithm, where is the problem in the python implementation / statistic simulation? Making booleans for the states is not a so good idea, just remember the last useful information / the number for the corresponding state. Here state $0$ corresponds to "nothing useful (for the task)" (e.g. empty string or string terminating in $H$ without $TTH$ in it), and i will denote "nothing useful by $\star$, $1$ stays for a terminal $\star T$, $2$ for a terminal $\star TT$, and $3$ is the success state $\star TTH$. So where is the problem now?

Comment: @saulspatz I think TTH (and THH and HHT and HTT) has expectation $8$, while THT (and HTH) has expectation $10$ and TTT (and HHH) has expectation $14$.  TT alone has expectation $6$ while TH has expectation $4$

Comment: @Henry Yes, I made a silly mistake.  Sorry.

Comment: Programming homework ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust no, it's a game from Kakegurui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go your way by adapting the below code for the own taste.
The written code should work in both Python2 and Python3.
(Well, in py2 one should better use `xrange` at that one point instead of `range`. That unused variable `trial` may become an underscore.)
The states are declared as strings, i do not see the point of encoding them as integers, the (needed) passages are encoded in a dictionary `dic`.

```
import random

random.seed(2021)

states = ['', 'T', 'TT', 'TTH']
T, H = 'T', 'H'
dic = { (T, '') : 'T', (T, 'T') : 'TT', (T, 'TT') :  'TT', 
        (H, '') :  '', (H, 'T') :   '', (H, 'TT') : 'TTH', }

N, totalsteps = 10**6, 0    # trials
for trial in range(N):
    state, steps = '', 0.0
    while state != 'TTH':
        toss = random.choice('TH')    # either T or H
        steps += 1
        state = dic[ (toss, state) ]
    totalsteps += steps

print('Statistic expectation is {}'.format(totalsteps/ N))
```

The simulation above has `N` steps, feel free to adjust this number. This time i've got (for the specified random seed - just comment it and rerun some times for diversity)...

```
Statistic expectation is 8.012544
```

Comment: This implements the given algorithm in a very pedestrian way. To have it in a general situation, one has to (write a routine to) compute first the (needed) states recording the "progress" done so far after each tossing, some combinatorial issues will appear when there are "repetitions" inside the string to be finally obtained. The `dic` is obtained after that fairly easy. Note that the general problem is "known"... A search for *coin tossing pattern* delivered for instance... https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135B/materials/pat.pdf - a compact pdf for a quick sample overview

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the simulation for the algorithm :-)

```
from random import randint

last_three = []
waiting = [0,0,1] # sequence TTH
s = 0

for x in range(1000) : # 1000 trials

    v = 0 # number of flips in one trial

    while True :

        v += 1
        
        if len(last_three) < 3 : last_three.append(randint(0,1)) 

        else : # keep just the last three values
            last_three.pop(0) 
            last_three.append(randint(0,1))

        if last_three == waiting : break

    s += v 

print(s/(x+1)) # Expected value
```

It's easy to modify this code to obtain the expected value for any sequence of $T$ and $H$ if you are interested to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be make one big list of flips and search for instances of `TTH`:

```
n = 100000000;
ps = SequencePosition[
   RandomChoice[{"T", "H"}, n],
   {"T", "T", "H"},
   Overlaps -> False
];
expectedFlips = ps[[-1, 2]]/Length@ps
```